# How to set com.google.firebase:firebase-database library in project

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

How to setup `com.google.firebase:firebase-database` library in new android studio project.

When I'm implement library similar as ...

This type complete setup of `firebase database` but error generated this type !

> WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'. It will be
>   removed at the end of 2019. For more information, see
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
>   determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use
>   -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information. Affected Modules: app

My App Gradle display here ...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firebase.mental.firebaseandhive"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'

}
```

Project gradle : .........

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'. It will be
>   removed at the end of 2019. For more information, see
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
>   determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use
>   -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information. Affected Modules: app

Comment: Have you complete your firebase application process.

Comment: Yes, this is a complete process ...

Comment: It is a **warning** not an error. It is related to the google play services plugin that uses the deprecated method variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()

Comment: Downgrade to `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` and it will work.